# In the following question I implemented the Jacobi iteration method

Tags: python

I used Latex for the math formatting.

[image]

My code:

```
import numpy as np 
from pprint import pprint
from numpy import array, zeros, diag, diagflat, dot

def jacobi(A,b,N=100,x=None):
    """Solves the equation Ax=b via the Jacobi iterative method."""
    # Create an initial guess if needed                                                                                                                                                            
    if x is None:
        x = zeros(len(A[0]))

    # Create a vector of the diagonal elements of A                                                                                                                                                
    # and subtract them from A                                                                                                                                                                     
    D = diag(A)
    R = A - diagflat(D)

        # Iterate for N times                                                                                                                                                                          
    for i in range(N):
         x = (b - dot(R,x)) / D
    return x

A = np.array([[3.0, 1.0, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],[1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], [0., 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], [0., 0, 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], [0., 0., 0., 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0., 0., 0., 0.], [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0., 0., 0.], [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0., 0.], [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0.], [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.0, 3.0, 1.0], [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.0, 3.0]])
b = np.array([1.0,1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0])
guess = np.array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])

sol = jacobi(A,b,N=100,x=guess)

print ("A:")
pprint(A)

print ("b:")
pprint(b)

print ("x:")
pprint(sol)
```

Which gives the output

```
A:
array([[3., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [1., 3., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 1., 3., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 1., 3., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 1., 3., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 3., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 3., 1., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 3., 1., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 3., 1.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 3.]])
b:
array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
x:
array([0.27638191, 0.17085427, 0.21105528, 0.1959799 , 0.20100503,
   0.20100503, 0.1959799 , 0.21105528, 0.17085427, 0.27638191])
```

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: Two of us solved your stated question.  Asking follow-up questions, especially those that show a lack of attempt on your part, are outside the Stack Overflow boundaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure what you're meaning by your double-bar operator, I presume a vector norm?  if so, maybe something like this:

```
def jacobi(A,b,N=100,x=None,tol=1e-15):
    """Solves the equation Ax=b via the Jacobi iterative method."""
    # Create an initial guess if needed                                                                                                                                                            
    if x is None:
        x = zeros(len(A[0]))

    # Create a vector of the diagonal elements of A                                                                                                                                                
    # and subtract them from A                                                                                                                                                                     
    D = diag(A)
    R = A - diagflat(D)

        # Iterate for N times                                                                                                                                                                          
    for i in range(N):
        x2 = (b - dot(R,x)) / D
        delta = np.linalg.norm(x - x2)
        if delta < tol:
            return x2
        x = x2

    warnings.warn(f"did not converge within {N} iterations")

    return x
```

Comment: thanks for your post, so how can I put this into my code to make it work? what else do I need from mine?

Comment: if you could edit that in I could accept the answer!

Comment: so I should replace this with my current jacobi function, but what about counting how many operations? shouldn't that be in the output also?

Comment: it's already doing the counting, I left you `i` counter in there if you want to return it…  if you're struggling to alter it to return that I'd suggest some basic python tutorials

Comment: so then I should return i if i want to print the count?

Comment: once i have the count i will be finished!

Comment: i believe its 79 iterations! but how do i return that? i will accept your answer anyways for your help!

Comment: @user123: Stack Overflow is not a line-by-line coding service.  We expect your due diligence as stated in the posting guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to write code to calculate `||A||` for a matrix `A`.  Save the old matrix in `x_old`; after you iterate,subtract the old and new matrices and calculate that error figure.  Compare it to 10^(-15).

```
x_old = x
error = 1.0     # Dummy value
iter_ct = 0
while error > 10 ** (-15):
    x = (b - dot(R, x_old)) / D
    error = <calculate || x - x_old || here>
    iter_ct += 1
    x_old = x
return x, iter_ct
```

Comment: could you edit that? once it works I can accept the solution!

Comment: What sort of editing?  We're not a repair shop for code; each of the answers solves your problem, if you'll only do the appropriate insertion.

Comment: how do I insert this into my code then? where would I put it?

Comment: I gave you code to replace your iteration loop, as requested.
@Sam Mason gave you the entire function.
Given the code you've already written you should easily have the skills to make either of these insertions; the two solutions are essentially identical.

Comment: I am getting an error from yours on the error = line, shouldn't it also output the number of iterations?

Comment: I inserted iteration count code; note that you should have been able to do that.  As for the error, what code did you insert to do the calculation?

Comment: i used np.linalg.norm(x-x_old)  and got 79 now i just need to figure out how to print it out, so thanks!